# Conditionals that are easy to read and understand

Tags: conditionals

I am probably overthinking this, but I am having a problem with how I should construct conditionals.

Are all of the example sentences below correct? Are some of them better than the others? In that case, why?  Does it matter if the "if" or the "then" comes first? Should there be a comma between the "if" and the "then" part? Are there better ways to construct conditionals that are easy to read and understand?

These strike me as more straightforward:

1. "If the initial requirements had been changed these follow-up questions could have led to divergent design choices."
2. "These follow-up questions could have led to divergent design choices if the initial requirements had been changed."

These strike me as what I would call "nicer", for some reason:

3. "These follow-up questions could have led to divergent design choices had the initial requirements been changed."
4. "Had the initial requirements been changed these follow-up questions could have led to divergent design choices."

Comment: If you have to ask if they are correct, you need English Language Learners. So this question is likely to be put on hold. If you want to know why the "had" version sounds better than the "if...had" variant — a style question — it is because the former is shorter and does not leave you hanging between the "if" and the "had". It is a slightly more advanced construction (a child would use "if...had") and so sounds more sophisticated. My opinion rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They all seem grammatically correct to me, however I find the first two much easier to grasp.

I think it's because:

- they begin with 'if' - so we already are primed to expect something conditional
- they follow a process in time from a, to b, to c - rather than the latter two, which go from b, to c, to a - which rather had me scratching my head, trying to work out 'what happened when, and what was dependent on... whaaat?'

If you added 'then' after the 'changed' in sentence 1. It would make it even easier to understand. This is because 'if' and 'then' can clearly delineate where your conditional clauses begin and end - it separates them so we can more easily get 'what is going on' - how the pieces of the sentence relate or are dependent on each other.

While 'had' is also conditional here, it is not always so - as it has other meanings, and so 'had' gives a less-clear signal than 'if' - that this is a conditional sentence, which also contributes to making the latter two sentences more difficult to understand.